# Enhanced Flex textarea / text viewer components?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is there any advanced textarea() component (AS3) for Flex available that could be used for both  viewing/exiting text nicely?

It would be good to have a text select feature, too.

Comment: TextArea can be used to edit/view text nicely. You'll have to explain a bit more what you mean by that; i.e. what feature you need that the built-in components do not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grant Skinner's [TextFlowPro](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2009/01/editable_multif.html) seems very cool. Not sure what you mean by this question exactly, though.